# File system corruption on ubuntu

Tags: filesystem, fsck, data-corruption

My computer crashed while I was developing a C++ program. When I rebooted my computer everything seemed fine until I ran my C++ program. Everything acted... weird and wrong, I've tried some stuff, including completely deleting the code, copying it from github and compiling again.

It gives off a seg fault before even starting in a place where it shouldn't on a static variable. The same exact code works just fine on the cloud and was working fine before the crash. This led me to believe the crash corrupted the file system.

I've done a file system check on the boot menu, following [this link](https://www.linuxshelltips.com/fsck-repair-linux-file-system/) to no avail. Using `fsck /dev/sda3` is not working since I cannot unmount it.

I've tried running `fsck -nf /dev/sda3` and it gave me this output:

[image]

What can I do? How can I fix this issue? Everything on my system works roughly the same with small hickups here and there except for my program. Is this really caused by corrupted file system or is there something else?

Using ubuntu 22.04

Comment: You missed the "boot from CD/DVD or USB install media, and run the check" part of the instructions.  That way your root filesystem with problems is not mounted.